Unable to pause Kafka consumer
I am working in java springboot, want to pause consumer for certain time period I am trying following code but looks like it is not working. Because when I debug code goes into 2nd if also. I am assuming when paused it shouldnt be in running state. Please guide me how can I manage this ?
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000) // Check every 5 seconds
public void checkTopicMessageCount() {
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("v2")).isRunning()) {
        int a = 1;
    }
    kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("v2").pause();
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("v2")).isRunning()) {
        int a = 1;
    }
}

Below is my Kafka Listener config
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.response}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.group-id}", id = "v2", info = "Consumer", clientIdPrefix = "consumer-v2")


Your second if is getListenerContainer("") with empty listenerContainer. Is that correct ?

Hi I have got the answer we will see isPaused instead of isRunning

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
